# nginx how to passthrough frontend ip address to backend server (do not confuse passing through user ip address to backend)

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, fastcgi

I have server Front server:Apple and Back End server Orange

Just to be clear in first line I don't want to pass through user ip address through Apple to Orange as I already implemented that by using

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

My question is I want to pass through Front end server ip address to backend server because we have too many front end servers, so I will know which front end server send from. any ideas or example ?
I can't use REMOTE_ADDR since it's passing through user ip address.

thanks.

Comment: Inspect all your headers, because you *should* find it at `REMOTE_ADDR`; what you're doing above is to set a header called `X_REAL_IP` with the value of the client IP. The front-end's IP will be in `REMOTE_ADDR`

Comment: The back end server will already know what address connected to it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any automatic way to do that. You can use `proxy_set_header frontend_ip <ipaddress>`.

The `<ipaddress>` is either added manually to the configuration or it is added by configuration management system when it generates configuration.

Then you can do anything with the header value in backend.

---

Old answer before question clarification

Your backend web servers are likely configured to replace connecting host IP address with address in `X-Real-IP` header.

You need to modify your backend server configuration so that they do not use `X-Real-IP`.

For example, in nginx, remove `real_ip_header` and `set_real_ip_from` lines from configuration.

Also make sure that your backend applications are not using `REMOTE_ADDR` but the actual header instead.

Comment: changing backend application from REMOTE_ADDR to X-Real-IP is not an option because of nature of application we can't change those settings do you have any idea other than REMOTE_ADDR I can pass a variable which I can define on front end server ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution you just need to use HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FROM  at backend server and you can see frontend ip address by using this. works perfectly.